# SAP - Code Coverage Analyzer Results

Tags: code-coverage, abap, code-analysis

I'm trying to extract the results from my Code Coverage analysis from my own abap program from the database in SAP.

At the following website [Coverage Analyzer: Technology](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73ehp1/helpdata/en/49/26f400c93016b8e10000000a42189d/content.htm) I find this information:
Initially, RSCVR_COLLECT transfers data to the 'staging area' of table COVRES0. Finally, the new data is aggregated with the statistics in tables COVRES and COVREF, among others.

In the table COVRES i can see one row where my program is listed but there are no further information about statistics like branch coverage, etc.

Can anybody give me a hint, where I can find the results of the Code Coverage Analyzer, so I am able to extract them for further processing?

Best regards
Bernhard

Comment: I found a solution - hope this helps also others who are facing the same Problem. Instead of using the buildin Code Coverage Analyzer (scov), use the Cover API. You can find the documentation here: [link](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73ehp1/helpdata/en/38/bce1d928004490907d3b10739f5f18/content.htm?frameset=/en/72/d9d255a08347e7aca81caad907234f/frameset.htm)

Comment: It's a good idea to add that as an answer. It's okay to answer your own questions - it makes it easier for others to find the solution

Answer (score 1):

*Copied from the comments above:*

Instead of using the code for Code Coverage Analyzer (scov), use the [Coverage API](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73ehp1/helpdata/en/38/bce1d928004490907d3b10739f5f18/content.htm?frameset=/en/72/d9d255a08347e7aca81caad907234f/frameset.htm/%20%22Coverage%20API'.).

Interfaces IF_SCV* in SE24